# Cross Product Index Notation Proof - Do not understand step

Tags: proof-explanation, index-notation, kronecker-delta

I am working through the document here:

[Index Notation Notes](http://www.ees.nmt.edu/outside/courses/GEOP523/Docs/index-notation.pdf)

One thing that has confused me is the proof of the Tripe Cross Product on page 9 of this document.

Specifically,  do not get how we go from the following line of the proof:

$\delta_{jh}\delta_{ki}a_ib_jc_k\hat{e}_h - \delta_{ji}\delta_{kh}a_ib_jc_k\hat{e}_h$

= $a_ib_jc_i\hat{e}_j - a_ib_ic_k\hat{e}_k$

Can someone please explain how these two are equal?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\delta_{jh}\hat{e}_h=\hat{e}_j$ while $\delta_{ki}c_k=c_i$, the first term on the left-hand side is $a_ib_jc_i\hat{e}_h$. Similarly, the term subtracted from it is $a_i\left(\delta_{ji}b_j\right)c_k\left(\delta_{kh}\hat{e}_h\right)=a_ib_ic_k\hat{e}_k$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of the delta notation, $\delta_{ki}c_k=c_i$ and similarly $\delta_{jh}\hat e_h=\hat e_j$. Substitute these into the first term and do the analogous in the second term to get the explanation.